# Split a vector in a list of vectors of same size using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a vector

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

How do I split this vector in same size chunks? Is there any purrr function to solve this problem?

For example,

```
f(x, 2)


[[1]]
1,2
[[2]]
3,4
[[3]]
5,6
[[4]]
7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
vector_list<-list(x[1:2], x[3:4], x[5:6], x[7:8] )
```